# Frame range for Render layers

Tags: rendering, layers

how to set frame range for layers. for example layer 1, start frame should be 1 and end frame should be 10. layer 2, start frame should be 20 and end frame should be 35.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You might just have to render each layer separately.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but any other suggestions rather than manual rendering in cycles

Comment: If the 2nd layer needs to be visible whilst the 1st is doing it's thing, you can always slide the 2nd layer's keyframes to the right in the Dopesheet so they start instead at frame 20.

Comment: you can also duplicate your scene (plus button at the top the screen) and then use the Video editing tools in Blender to sequence each Scene in a final video. I have done this a few times. For instance Scene 1 is the intro, scene 2 is the animation and scene 3 is the outro. In VSE just use the ADD Scene and select your scene.

Answer (score 5):

You can animate layer's **Disable or Enable** using <kbd>I</kbd>.

Set keyfrimes like you set keyframes for object visibility:

For example, for start frame on the 20th and end on the 35th, you should set 3 keyframes: off - anywhere before 20 frame, on - on the 20th frame, off - on the 35th frame

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it works and saved me more time

Comment: @RajKumarT Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient privileges to upvote answers you like, which is the Blender way of saying thank you.

Comment: great, it works.

Comment: In 2.80+ (I'm using 3.4.1) the way to do this seems to be to animate the "Use for Rendering" checkbox on the View Layer Properties tab in the Properties editor.